# How to know if these congresses (i.e. organized by ISCA) are good?

Tags: conference

One of my colleages has published a couple of papers in the CS congresses organized by:
http://www.isca-hq.org/

For what I saw that the papers that got accepted in their conferences, are indexed in DBLP and INSPEC. Actually I would like to submit one paper in the conferences that they organized, but I am a little dubious about it. My main concern is to know if it would be a good idea to submit to that conference.

Could anybody give me his straight opinion about those congresses that they organized? do they seem good enough?

thanks

Comment: Have you ever cited (or even read) a paper from those conferences?  If so, was it a _good_ paper?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consulting the [Australian Computer Science Conference Ranking](http://core.edu.au/cms/images/downloads/conference/08sort%20acronymERA2010_conference_list.pdf) reveals that one of their conferences, CATA, is ranked C. I did not check any others.

Indicators   that the conferences are not good include:

- The conference is extremely broad. CATA covers topics including Algorithms, Programming Languages, and Multimedia.
- The conference is in an exotic location (e.g. Hawaii).
- People involved in the conference are not the leaders in their field.
- Conference is not well established.
- Conference does not appear in the Conference Ranking list, even though it has been around for a long time.

Note that conferences satisfying some or all of these criteria are not necessarily poorly ranked.

Comment: How is an exotic location an indicator of anything? The top software engineering and HCI conferences tend to alternate between the US and an "exotic" location.

Comment: @AustinHenley: Certain low quality conferences appear always in Hawaii.

Comment: My (limited) experience suggests that conferences that are in "tourist" destinations tend to be less productive, as more people are distracted with things other than the conference. Also, good conferences do not need a gimmick of a tourist hotspot to attract presenters. Of course this is just a general observation, and isn't a hard rule to suggest *all conferences* at tourist locations are bad.

Comment: @AndyW: None of my rules are hard. They are indicators.

Comment: thank you for your advice @DaveClarke, one question, do you know other computer science conference rankings apart of the one that you mentioned?